# php and mysql insert checkbox value error

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert a checkbox value to mysql database using php.

**HTML input:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="notepad"><label>Notepaa+</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="java"><label>java</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Openoffice<label>OpenOffice</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="python"><label>python</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="virtualbox<label>VirtualBox</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="chrome"><label>Chrome</label>
```

But this have a problem,if I check more than 1 checkbox in HTML code, it will insert two record to database.

**php code**

```
<?php
include("insert.php");
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$s=implode(" ",$subject);

if($_POST["submit"]=="submit")
{
   $query="INSERT INTO `test` (`subject`) VALUES ('$s')";
   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}
if( $_POST )
{
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   echo $query;
}
?>
```

How to fix this bug?

Comment: edit with echo $query;

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer i edit (echo 'your choose is:'.implode(',',$subject); )with( echo $query;) but still will insert two record.

Comment: edit your question with the output of echo $query to see your sql query, this is not the solution

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer ok, i edit the question with echo $query;

Comment: write the output of echo $query in your question, please

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer the output is INSERT INTO `test` (`subject`) VALUES ('notepad java Openoffice')

Comment: edit your question with the code into insert.php. 
apparently there's the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the SQL query. This happens because the PHP code(especially the line `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`) gets called twice when you submit the form.

Take a look at the PHP for submission tutorials below and understand the proper way of doing this.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
2. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: You have the same string with your modification

Comment: @Rocket Surgeon I try your solution , but still will insert two record.

Comment: Okay. So do you mind if I suggest to insert a line of code (`die(var_dump($query));`) just after (`$query="INSERT INTO `test` (`subject`) VALUES ('".$s."')";`) and please comment what is the output you get now.

Comment: @Rocket Surgeonthe output is string(65) "INSERT INTO `test` (`subject`) VALUES ('notepad java Openoffice')"

Comment: @Rocket Surgeon In PHPMyAdmin , the sql can run normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`subject`) VALUES (....)
```

Expects a single value for the column `subject` not a list of values.

Meaning that your SQL will only insert one row at a time. If you are getting more than one row inserted then it is coming from somewhere else.

Either

- you are getting the post of the data twice
- there is another execution of the same query.

Your SQL is not the problem here.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

your implementation seems to be right, but I think the cause of the duplication is the html.. in which your html tags are incorrect:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Openoffice<label>OpenOffice</label>
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="virtualbox<label>VirtualBox</label>
```

you forgot the closing `>` tag for the `input`

```
<input ... >
```

it should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Openoffice" /><label>OpenOffice</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="virtualbox /><label>VirtualBox</label>
```

Sometimes, during parsing of the input values the php can be confused what to add in the array.. so when you implode there is a possibility of duplication of values or unintended results..

I think your code will work fine after that...

Comment: I try your solution , but still will insert two record.